# jQuery Datetime picker MVC3

Tags: asp.net-mvc

I have in my Model this field

```
[DataType(DataType.DateTime)]
    [Required(ErrorMessage = "Expire is required")]
    public DateTime Expire
    {
      get;
      set;
    }
```

In My View

```
@Html.EditorFor(model => model.Expire))
      @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.Expire)
```

and I create DataTime EditorTemplates

```
@inherits System.Web.Mvc.WebViewPage<System.DateTime>
@Html.TextBox("", (Model.ToShortDateString()), new { @class = "datePicker" })
<script type='text/javascript'>
  $(document).ready(function () {
    $(".datePicker").datepicker({
      //      buttonImage: "/content/images/calendar.gif",
      //      showOn: "both",
      //      defaultDate: $("#calendar-inline").attr('rel')
      showAnim: 'slideDown',
      dateFormat: 'dd/mm/yyyy'

    });
  });
</script>
```

when i try to Create new Item I have this error message

> The model item passed into the
>   dictionary is null, but this
>   dictionary requires a non-null model
>   item of type 'System.DateTime'

I try

```
Model.HasValue ? Model.Value.ToString("MM/dd/yyyy") : DateTime.Today.ToShortDateString()
```

But i not have in Model Value check

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Try one of the following:

- If the action is for creating a new object pass a new instance as model, e.g. `return View(new MyObject())`
- Change `@inherits System.Web.Mvc.WebViewPage<System.DateTime>` to `@inherits System.Web.Mvc.WebViewPage<System.DateTime?>`

Answer (score 2):

```
@inherits System.Web.Mvc.WebViewPage<System.DateTime>
```

should be

```
@inherits System.Web.Mvc.WebViewPage<System.DateTime?>
```

Answer (score 1):

Just put ? in your System.DateTime

example :

```
@model System.DateTime?

@Html.TextBox("", ViewData.TemplateInfo.FormattedModelValue,
                new
                {
                    data_datepicker = true
                })
```

if you ommit the question mark you will ge an error

Answer (score 0):

This is the code of my editor template: The point is to avoid null values:

```
@model DateTime?


<script src="../../../Scripts/jquery-1.4.4.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
<script src="../../../Scripts/jquery-ui.js" type="text/javascript"></script>

           @Html.TextBox("", (Model.HasValue ? Model.Value.ToShortDateString() : String.Empty), new { @class = "datePicker" })
<script type='text/javascript'>
    $(document).ready(function () {
        $(".datePicker").datepicker({
            //      buttonImage: "/content/images/calendar.gif",
            //      showOn: "both",
            //      defaultDate: $("#calendar-inline").attr('rel')
            showAnim: 'slideDown',
            dateFormat: 'dd/mm/yyyy'

        });
    });
</script>
```