# MVC 3 - Change Html.TextBox to Html.TextBoxFor

Tags: asp.net-mvc-3, validation, html-helper

I am using html.textbox for 2 of my datetime field because I need to format them in a specific format but i don't know how to do it by html.textboxfor.
However, I realise i need to have the textboxfor for the validation in my model class to work:

```
  [Required(ErrorMessage = "Storage Date is required")]
  [DataType(DataType.DateTime, ErrorMessage = "Please input a valid date")]
  public DateTime StorageDate { get; set; }
```

Any idea how can I change my Html.Textbox below into Html.TextBoxFor with the same setting??

```
  @Html.TextBox("expirydate", String.Format("{0:ddd, d MMM yyyy}", DateTime.Now), new { id = "expirydate" })
    @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.ExpiryDate)
```

Appreciate any help... Thanks...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You don't really **need** to use `TextBoxFor()` for validation to work. If your TextBox has the same id as a field in the model, the model binder will pick it up. If you're talking about to get the unobtrusive validation features, you can always manually add the data-* attributes to your TextBox.

However, in this case it sounds like what you really want is a custom editor, using `EditorFor()`. It's a bit more work, but it will allow you to actually enforce the date/time formatting by giving the user something like a date/time picker control. The basic idea is:

- Create a partial view called DateTime.cshtml that is bound to model of type `Nullable<DateTime>`, and put it into the `Shared/EditorTemplates` view folder.
- Use jQuery and jQueryUI to put an HTML textbox that is styled as a date/time picker into the partial view.
- Decorate the property on your model with the `[DataType(DataType.DateTime)]` attribute
- Use `Html.EditorFor(model => model.WhateverProperty)`

Fortunately, date/time pickers are probably the most popular custom MVC3 editor, so there are plenty of examples to pick from; the code from [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4617410/jquery-datetime-picker-mvc3) works fine, just make sure to note the suggestion in the answer and replace this line in the partial view:

```
@inherits System.Web.Mvc.WebViewPage<System.DateTime>
```

with this:

```
@model System.DateTime?
```

Comment: HI, thanks a lot but actually i used editorfor previously. However, I need to do some different setting on each of the datetime field datepicker, so i separate it with different id. Btw, I also noticed I do not really need the textboxfor for validation to work!